# Using an adapter from another class

Tags: android

I want to use an adapter from another class. But apparently there is something wrong because when I type a value in the search bar the app crashed, the log says:

```
lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
```

This is my code where I want to use the adapter in onQueryTextChange method:

```
public class FindSkill extends AppCompatActivity { 
ArrayAdapter myAdapter;
@Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                Parser parser = new Parser(FindSkill.this, data, listView);
                myAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) parser.listView.getAdapter();

                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query.toString());
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return false;
            }
```

Parser class code:

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask <Void, Void,Integer> {

    Context ctx;
    ListView listView;
    String data;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();


    public Parser(Context ctx, String data, ListView listView) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.data=data;
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parse();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if (integer == 1) {
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Unable to Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private int parse() {


        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            titles.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = jo.getString("post_title");
                titles.add(title);
            }
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
myAdapter=(ArrayAdapter) parser.listView.getAdapter();
```

**EDIT:**

try to use Interface for callback:

Create interface class.

```
public interface TaskDelegate {
    public void taskCompletionResult();
}
```

Then pass in Parse class and when task is complete call callback method.

```
Context ctx;
ListView listView;
String data;
ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
TaskDelegate taskDelegate;


public Parser(Context ctx, String data, ListView listView, TaskDelegate taskDelegate) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.data=data;
    this.listView = listView;
    this.taskDelegate=taskDelegate;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parse();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);

    if (integer == 1) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        taskDelegate.taskCompletionResult();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Unable to Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
.
.
.
.
```

Then implement interface and it

```
public class FindSkill extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskDelegate{ 
ArrayAdapter myAdapter;
Parser parser=nulll;
String qry=null;

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
      qry=query;
      parser = new Parser(FindSkill.this, data, listView,this);
      return false;
}

public void taskCompletionResult()
{
       myAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) parser.listView.getAdapter();
       myAdapter.getFilter().filter(qry.toString());
       myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I can't use myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query.toString()); in taskCompletionResult() method because query isn'r defied there. and this line also includes error: 
Parser parser = new Parser(FindSkill.this, data, listView,this);

Comment: Now there is an error in  parser = new Parser(FindSkill.this,data, listView.this); --> in listView.this --> class name is expected

Comment: use `listView,this` in between llistview and this is comma.

Comment: how I didn't get it.

Comment: Your `Parse` class has 4 parameters in Constructor. thats why i added 4th parameter is `this`.